# kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host when connecting to sftp over https/ssl proxy

Tags: proxy, ssl, sftp, openssl, squid

I am trying to connext to sftp server over https proxy, using the following command:

```
sftp -v -o ProxyCommand="nc -X connect -x proxyIp:3128 %h %p" user@sftpIP 22.
```

When I am running the above command I got

> kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
> Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535

I am using squid proxy as my proxy server and trying to connect to sftp over https proxy. I was able to successfully connect over HTTP Proxy. Not sure how to debug this futhuer as well as nothing is clear from this error message.

On Using the command `nc -X connect -x proxyIp:3128 sftpIP 22` , It got stuck at debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1

Comment: Does the specified proxy command, _on its own,_ successfully connect to the server to the point of showing you the "SSH-2.0" banner?

Comment: Please try running the proxy command "nc -X connect -x proxyIp:3128 sftpIP 22" by itself and [edit] your question to show the result of running it.

Comment: Yes I run the command nc -X connect -x proxyIp:3128 sftpIP 22 , It got stuck at debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1